# nunit2 task , NAnt , Watin - ApartmentState STA error

Tags: nunit, nant, watin

I am exploring WatIN automation framework driven by NUnit and Nant. I have Apartmentstate set in App.config

```
<NUnit>
    <TestRunner>
      <!-- WatiN can only host IE in STA mode -->
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA"/>
    </TestRunner>
</NUnit>
```

I have also set [TestFixture, RequiresSTA] in test class. This works perfectly fine when i use nunit-console testrunner or Nunit GUI runner.

Using Nunit2 runner in NAnt throws this exception

[nunit2] : [DEBUG] The CurrentThread needs to have it's ApartmentState set to ApartmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer

How do I workaround this issue?

Thanks 
Jenga

Comment: Did you try [TestFixture(ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA)] 
and also see https://groups.google.com/group/testdrivenusers/browse_thread/thread/0bbd753de17a8383/7edef951a8ca415b?lnk=raot&fwc=1&hl=km

Comment: Both of them didnt work :(. Still investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I was able to fix it by adding the /nothread arg when calling nunit-console.exe from my nant target.

Example:

```
<exec verbose="true" 
    workingdir="${project::get-base-directory()}\build"
    program="tools\nunit\nunit-console.exe" basedir="${project::get-base-directory()}">

    <arg value="${ua-testproject.name}" />
    <arg value="/nothread" />
    <arg value="/xml:${ua-tests.report}" />
</exec>
```